# Node.js random number generator?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is for a Twitch.tv chat bot when someone types `!random`, it would reply with a random number between `1`-`100`. I've tried `var p1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);` but i'm not sure how to integrate that into the code below in the `client.say("");` section. Cheers to anyone that can help me with this.

```
client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
      if (message === "!random" && canSendMessage) {
        canSendMessage = false;
        client.say("");
        setTimeout(function() {
          canSendMessage = true
        }, 2000);
```

Comment: Just pass `p1` to `client.say` instead of `""`. Ex: `client.say(p1)`.

Comment: It gives me this error when i do that. /Users/Billy/node_modules/tmi.js/lib/utils.js:64
  return channel.charAt(0) === "#" ? channel.toLowerCase() : "#" + channel.toLowerCase();

Comment: Looks like you need to convert it to a string first. `p1.toString()`.

Comment: How many `!random` could be in one message? Could there be more of them? Do you want them all to be replaced? Could the message contain other things? Post an example of a message and the a desired output of that message!

Comment: @MikeC I just did that. It actually puts a number in the chat but it keeps putting the same number, instead of putting a different one each time.

Comment: Please don't remove your question after it's been answered.  1) Other people may find it useful in the future.  2) Without the question, the answers aren't guaranteed to make sense to anyone viewing this in the future.

Answer (score 3):

`client.say()` the random number after you converted it to a string:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
client.say(rand.toString());
```

---

Note that `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)` will generate a random number between 0 and 99, not between 1 and 100.

You may want to add one to the result:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
```

Comment: or just multiply by 101.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Changed my answer. Both my original answer and your suggestion is incorrect, as `Math.random()` gives a random number between zero and one, zero inclusive, one exclusive. Both `Math.ceil(0 * 100)` and `Math.floor(0 * 101)` equal zero, which is less than one.

Comment: `Math.random` is never `1`. I tought the same my selfe but it's not.

Comment: Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) out! It sais that `Math.random` return a number in the range `[0, 1)` (1 excluded)

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Well yeah, that's exactly what I said. While one is exclusive, zero is not, so zero is a valid result of `Math.random()`.

Comment: You're right I didn't notice he wanted the result from `1`. Then an old `rand * (max - min) + min` like you did will suffice!

Comment: @Timo I tried what you said above, it actually puts a number in the chat but it keeps putting the same number, instead of putting a different one each time. I used client.say(rand.toString());

Answer (score 1):

If the message could contain other things and if it can contain more than just one occurence of `!random` (like `"Howdy! Here is a random number !random. Here is another !random."`), then use this:

```
client.on('chat', function(channel, user, message, self) {
    if (canSendMessage) { // don't check if message is equal to '!random'
        canSendMessage = false;

        message = message.replace(/!random/g, function() {
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)) + 1;
        });

        client.say(message);

        setTimeout(function() {
            canSendMessage = true
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```